# Audio file content type changed when uploaded to S3 with boto3/ How to upload a file to S3 subdirectory in a bucket with Tinys3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, twilio, boto3

I'm working on Python Twilio app and using Amazon Polly to convert text to speech. As you may know, `Twilio <play>` verb can play sound files only from `url`. Now I can convert the text to speech audio with **Amazon Polly** and upload the audio file to S3 and let Twilio play it with public url.

But when I use boto3 to upload the mp3 files to S3, the content types are changed to **binary/ octet-stream** which is not supported by Twilio. I tried to use content-type parameter in boto3  but didn't work out. When I use `tinys3` library, it works. However, I cannot upload the file to S3 subdirectory. Tinys3 can only upload to bucket. I googled but haven't seen any example about tinys3 uploading a file to S3 subdirectory.

So could you please help me out in either content type issue with boto3 or uploading a file to S3 subdirectory in a bucket with Tinys3?

Answer (score 0):

In AWS S3 everything within a bucket is considered as an [object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingObjects.html). There's nothing like you can't upload to sub directory. `test_subdir/test_file.txt` is treated as just an object in a S3 bucket.

Uploading a file to S3 subdirectory in a bucket with Tinys3:

```
import tinys3
conn = tinys3.Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY,tls=True)

f = open('test_file.txt','rb')
print (conn.upload('test_subdir/test_file.txt',f,'test_bucket'))
print (conn.get('test_subdir/test_file.txt','test_bucket'))
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very Venkatesh.. this really helped.. I just tried and it worked.. great

Comment: Glad to know that it worked and helped you. Please 'mark answer as accepted' if it served the purpose or helped you to fix.